# Typing characters found in Portuguese

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

In my text entry settings, I have `Portuguese (Brazil)`.

However, I looked at the layout chart and it appears there is no `ã` character (`a` with tilde) which is a very common character in Portuguese. Also absent is the `ç` character (`c` with cedilla).

How do I type these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce the ã character, press first the <kbd>~</kbd> (red box 1 in picture) and then <kbd>a</kbd> (red box 2 in picture).

ç is produced by pressing the key designated in the green box.

[image]